# Windows 10 custom scaling for different displays

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

My laptop has a hi dpi screen, 100% is too small for me so I changed to 125%, it looks better but the font of some softwares (including MS outlook) becomes blurry.

One of my friends told me to set Custom scaling to 124%, surprisingly the font becomes clear! Now the problem is, Windows 10 only allows to set custom scale for all displays! When I connect to a monitor, the monitor's display has to be 124% as well! This is driving me crazy that spending a whole day to find a solution and then another problem comes out.

My questions are:

1. Why a custom scale of 124% can have clear font, while the font in 125% is blurry? Is this a bug of Windows 10?
2. Can I set custom scale per display in Windows 10?

My Windows is Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.19)

Comment: which Windows 10 version do you use? test it in last Fall Creators update 16299

Comment: @magicandre1981 Updated the question with my version info, looks like we are on the same version. Can you set custom scale per display?

Comment: I'm still on Windows 8 on my dell-laptop which doesn't support this at all.